# Problem with GROUP BY statement (SQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I have a table GAMES with this information:

```
Id_Game  Id_Player1  Id_Player2  Week
--------------------------------------
1211     Peter       John        2
1215     John        Louis       13
1216     Louis       Peter       17
```

I would like to get a list of the last week when each player has played, and the number of games, which should be this:

```
Id_Player  Week  numberGames
-----------------------------
Peter      17    2
John       13    2
Louis      17    2
```

But instead I get this one **(notice on Peter week)**:

```
Id_Player  Week  numberGames
-----------------------------
Peter      2     2
John       13    2
Louis      17    2
```

What I do is this:

```
  SELECT Id_Player, 
         MAX(Week) AS Week, 
         COUNT(*) as numberGames 
    FROM ((SELECT Id_Player1 as Id_Player, Week 
             FROM Games) 
           UNION ALL
           (SELECT Id_Player2 as Id_Player, Week 
              FROM Games)) AS g2 
GROUP BY Id_Player;
```

Could anyone help me to find the mistake?

Comment: For what database?  You appear to not understand how aggregate functions work.

Comment: What if the second `Peter` isnt the same as the first `Peter`?

Comment: @Ardman To the database they are the same Peter, because they are returned only once by the GROUP BY.
To the app, maybe Id_Players are unique.

Comment: @user411103 The query should work as you intend. Why that many parentheses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the datatype of the `Week` column? If the datatype of `Week` is varchar you would get this behavior.

Comment: +1 Good spot. The code looks good otherwise. Edit: We'd have John and week 2 also though, no?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that I had created WEEK as a VARCHAR as you said. Now as an integer it works perfectly. THANK YOU all!